# Как сформировать запрос чтобы получить получить name, которые продавались только с единственного store_id

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное условие, сформировать с помощью одного select без with
Сам решил с with:

```
 with pr as (
 select product.name, product_id, store_id
 from sale
 join product
 using ( product_id )
 group by store_id, product_id)
 select name
 from pr
 group by product_id
 having count(*) = 1;
```

А оптимизировать не получается.

Comment: С помощью одного навряд ли получится...нужен вложенный запрос для проверки условия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product.name
FROM product 
JOIN sale USING ( product_id )
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT store_id) = 1
```